# jquery autocomplete from json *simple*

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, list, autocomplete

I have been researching for hours through S/O and google and trying many different options to get my autocomplete to work.  My original code worked but when I passed in a larger list it failed.  So I have moved to another type of script but I can't for the life of me make it work - I have been hitting a wall for awhile.

What I am trying to do is have my form fill out the autocomplete using companies that are in my json file.  I.e. it looks to see if the word exists in the .json file - if so it autofills.

Python is my go to language so I am a little out of sorts on jquery / js - forgive my lack of knowledge.

The json is formed as such:

```
{["Company1", "Company2", "Company3", etc...]}
```

Script & other pertinent code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#userSelect").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
          $.getJSON( "directory/name.json", {
            term: extractLast( request.term )
          }, response );
        }
      });
    });

<input type="text" id="userSelect" value="Will this ever work?" style="width: 300px;" />
```

If anyone has any help that would be great -- its been a full day struggle!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any error?
Can you create a fiddle for your problem

Comment: I don't see any obvious mistakes. Might as well be a problem with you server.

Comment: @Sandeeproop I have not used a fiddle before.  I will go try that. thanks.

Comment: @Sandeeproop its throwing up a : SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list error

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will solve your problem  http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp
check your data type in response in the console of firebug if your are using firefox browser

Comment: Thanks Sohail - I had originally tried using the remote-json but it was giving me some issues so I went this approach

Comment: If this has resolve your issue then please mark this as resolve thank you :)

Comment: Sorry i wrote that incorrectly -=- I originally went the remote-json route (which you described) but it didn't work so I tried the approach which I am asking help for.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

you already having json data,so no need to passing query,get json data passing into function,and finally return your source data only

```
source: function (request, response) {
    $.getJSON( "directory/name.json",function (data) {
       //do you stuff 
       var convert_array=[];
       //do your stuff,push your required data inside convert_array
       //return  as array data 
       response(convert_array);
    });
},
```